# How to change files in the sequential order of the loop

Tags: python

I have 25 json files in a folder, named 0.json through 24.json, and I am trying to batch open and rename a perimeter "image" inside of each, which currently all have a placeholder of "https://" in the "image" field.

The .json currently appears as follows for each json file:

```
{"image": "https://", "attributes": [{"trait_type": "box color", "value": "blue"}, {"trait_type": "box shape", "value": "square"}]}
```

but should be

```
{"image": "https://weburlofnewimage/0", "attributes": [{"trait_type": "box color", "value": "blue"}, {"trait_type": "box shape", "value": "square"}]}
```

I have a central folder on a site like dropbox, that has a url structure of https://weburlofnewimage/0, /1, /2 etc.  And so I would like to open each file, and change the value of the "image" key to be replaced with "https://weburlofnewimage/ + current file number + '.png'".

So far I am able to iterate through the files and change the image perimeter successfully within the json files, however the files seem to iterate in a random order, so on loop 1, I am getting file 20, and as a result file 20 is given file 0's image url.

Code as follows:

```
import json
import os

folderPath = r'/path/FolderWithJson/'
fileNumber = 0

for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
    print('currently on file ' + str(fileNumber))
    if not filename.endswith(".json"): continue
    filePath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
 
    with open(filePath, 'r+') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        data['image'] = str('https://weburlofnewimage/' + str(fileNumber) + '.png')
    print('opening file ' + str(filePath))
    
    os.remove(filePath)
    with open(filePath, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    print('removing file ' + str(filePath))

    fileNumber +=1
```

Which results in me getting the following printouts:

```
currently on file 10 (on loops 10)
currently preparing file 2.json (its working on file #2...)
opening file /path/FolderWithJson/2.json
removing file /path/FolderWithJson/2.json
```

And then when I look in 2.json I see the image is changed to "https://weburlofnewimage/10.png" instead of "https://weburlofnewimage/2.png"

Comment: Yes, `os.listdir` does not sort its output.  If the files have the number in their names, then just pull the number from the name.  I'll show you below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pull the number from the file name.  Don't use your own count.  And please remember you never need to use the `str` function on a string.  Many people seem to be getting that bad habit.

```
import json
import os

folderPath = '/path/FolderWithJson/'

for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
    if not filename.endswith(".json"): 
        continue
    fileNumber = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    print('currently on file', fileNumber)
    filePath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)

    print('opening file', filePath)
    with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        data['image'] = 'https://weburlofnewimage/'+fileNumber +'.png'

    print('rewriting file', filePath)
    with open(filePath, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open a file with a direct path, instead of iterating through the directory. I would use a for loop to insert the numbers into the path, that way they iterate in order.

```
for fileNumber in range(0,24):
  with open(f'my_file/{fileNumber}.json') as f:
    ...doMyCode...
```